# How to make SparkSession and Spark SQL implicits globally available (in functions and objects)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a project with many .scala files inside a package. I want to use Spark SQL as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                                      .appName("My app")
                                      .config("spark.master", "local")
                                      .getOrCreate()

// For implicit conversions like converting RDDs to DataFrames
import spark.implicits._
```

Is it a good practice to wrap the above code inside a singleton object like:

```
object sparkSessX{
   import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

   val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                                      .appName("My App")
                                      .config("spark.master", "local")
                                      .getOrCreate()

   // For implicit conversions like converting RDDs to DataFrames
   import spark.implicits._
}
```

and every class to extend or import that object?

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen it before, but the more Scala developers use Spark the more we see new design patterns emerge. That could be one.

I think you could instead consider making `val spark` implicit and pass it around where needed through this implicit context (as the second argument set of your functions).

I'd however consider making the object a trait (as I'm not sure you can extend Scala objects) and moreover to make room for other traits of your classes.